# Batch Change user Input to proper case

Tags: batch-file

How can i change `%name%` to proper case or Title Case and store it in another variable?

I have searched all over stackoverflow and all of the accepted answer i do not understand as this is my first ever batch file.

```
@echo off
set /p name= Name: 
mkdir %name%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make the first letter of user input a capital in a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107905/make-the-first-letter-of-user-input-a-capital-in-a-batch-script)

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php

Comment: Just add the following as your second line`echo WARNING typed entries are case sensitive`

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.toCamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite simple script that converts text to capitalised text, so every word begins with a capital letter and has small letters elsewhere. Supposing the batch file is called `capitalise.bat`, provide the text as command line argument like this: `capitalise.bat "tHIS is SOME sAmplE teXt"`, so it will be returned as `This Is Some Sample Text`. Here is the code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "TEXT=%~1"
set "$BUF="

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%L in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    set "TEXT=!TEXT:%%L=%%L!"
)
endlocal & set "TEXT=%TEXT%"

call :CAPITALISE %TEXT%

echo(%$BUF:~1%

endlocal
exit /B


:CAPITALISE
if "%~1"=="" exit /B
set "WORD=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "CHAR=!WORD:~,1!"
>&2 echo(!CHAR!
for %%L in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if /I "!CHAR!"=="%%L" set "CHAR=%%L"
)
>&2 echo(!CHAR!
for /F "delims=" %%K in ("!$BUF! !CHAR!!WORD:~1!") do (
    endlocal
    set "$BUF=%%K"
)
shift /1
goto :CAPITALISE
exit /B
```

Note that this is not capable of handling all special characters correctly. As word separators, the standard token separators <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=` and non-break space (`0xFF`) are taken. Characters with a code greater than `0x7F` are not changed in case.

It is very difficult to make a bullet-proof script that can deal with all (special) characters, code pages and with a custom set of word separators in a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), so I chose to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to use is to use string substitution:

```
SET name=%name:A=a%
SET name=%name:B=b%
...
SET name=%name:Y=y%
SET name=%name:Z=z%
```

Another option is to loop through all the substitutions to make it more compact:

```
FOR %%i IN ("A=a" "B=b" ... "Y=y" "Z=z") DO CALL SET "name=%%name:%%~i%%"
```

With the same system you can do title case:

```
set "name= %name%"
FOR %%i IN (" A= a" " B= b" ... " Y= y" " Z= z") DO CALL SET "name=%%name:%%~i%%"
set "name=%name:~1%"
```

With the additional spaces only the words starting characters are substituted.

[Source](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php)

Thanks to @aschipfl for his corrections and additions!

Comment: I think there are some `%` signs missing: `do call set "name=%%name:%%~i%%"`; note that the first word is not preceded by a space, so you should perhaps do `set "name= %name%"` before and `set "name=%name:* =%"` after the loop...

Comment: Wouldnt the last one delete everything up to the last part without space?

Comment: The last one would delete everything up to and including the first space; since the first line precedes the text with one space, the last line effectively removes that space again; you could also write `set "name=%name:~1%"` instead (remove the first character)...

Comment: Ok then I misunderstood something. Thanks for the corrections! Will edit them soon.